# Zabbix wrong Total memory get from VM

Tags: zabbix

```
Linux: Total memory
vm.memory.size[total]

Proxmox server (32gb ram)
VM1 + zabbix agent (1gb ram)
VM2 zabix server get mem info from VM1 and show wrong info.
```

Why? How Fix?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: solution https://github.com/kvaps/zabbix-linux-container-template

Comment: How did you determine that these values are wrong?